# div gets extra padding only in Chrome and only on home page

Tags: css

we've got an issue that only effects Chrome, Firefox and IE are fine.

the only page affected in Chrome is the home page, index.html... all other pages use the exact same header html and CSS. If we click a link on the home page to go to an interior page, the page works fine, then we click back to the home page and it looks fine... but if we refresh the home page, its messed up again.

here's the url

http://www.logilityconnectionseurope.com

the element that gets pushed down is a big div that holds an image and some text on the right side, the div CSS is as follows

```
.dateLogoTopDiv  {
float:right;
text-align:right;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">

    <img src="images/connections-europe-2013-logo-web.jpg" width="410" height="242" alt="connections europe 2013 logo" />

    <div class="dateLogoTopDiv">
        <img src="images/logility-logo.jpg" width="105" height="108" alt="logility logo" />
        <p>14-15 May 2013</p>
        <p>Hotel Le Plaza </p>
        <p>Brussels, Belgium</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

as I said, works fine in Firefox and IE and works in Chrome on every page except the index

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce the problem...

Comment: It's messed up in Safari too.  You have [bad HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.logilityconnectionseurope.com%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Fix it.

Comment: turns out the code is misbehaving on every page in Chrome, once each page is refreshed.

Comment: I'm a junior coder. If the html is bad, I dont quite know where or how to fix it. I'm asking for help, please.

Comment: The link is in my comment.  Click it.

Comment: validated correctly but problem is still there. Very weird behavior, click a link on the bar to an internal page, it behaves correctly... refresh the page and the problem shows up.

Comment: In your OP, please include the relevant HTML along with your CSS so this question remains useful to others long after you fix your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your page through the HTML Validator and fix all errors.  Without valid HTML, browsers don't know for sure what you intended to display and you'll have cross-browser rendering inconsistency.  In this case, Webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari).

[http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.logilityconnectionseurope.com/index.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

**EDIT:**

OP's site previously contained malformed HTML including open tags and misplaced tags.   OP's site has since been fixed, rendering the code at the URL posted in the question obsolete.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm seeing the OP's issues in Chrome.  I cannot explain why the issue was occurring or why it was intermittent.  However, I fixed it by *adding* the following...

**Additional CSS:**

```
.header {
    overflow: auto;
}

.header > img {
    float: left;
}
```

**Existing HTML:**

```
<div class="header">

    <img src="images/connections-europe-2013-logo-web.jpg" width="410" height="242" alt="connections europe 2013 logo" />

    <div class="dateLogoTopDiv">
        <img src="images/logility-logo.jpg" width="105" height="108" alt="logility logo" />
        <p>14-15 May 2013</p>
        <p>Hotel Le Plaza </p>
        <p>Brussels, Belgium</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

This takes the two main header elements and floats them left & right respectively. The right one was already floating to the right.  `overflow: auto;` is a trick to force the header to expand to contain it's floated elements.  Since both are floated, they are *outside* the regular content flow and would not normally cause the header to expand.

Comment: validated all - still having the same issue

Comment: @RoddeyPhipps, I'm still in Safari and your problem appears to be gone.

Comment: thank you... its still whacky in Chrome, altho it fixes itself if I go to an interior page

Comment: @RoddeyPhipps, you might be seeing some caching issues.  Do a hard refresh or try Chrome on another computer.  I looked at your code in the DOM inspector console and there's nothing else that could have caused this other than the invalid HTML.  The element has plenty of room.

Comment: Is anyone else seeing this problem? We're all on a company network and we're seeing it, but I'm wondering if those outside, are not seeing it..

Comment: the element in question, is a div, thats inside a header div. The header div includes the big logo on the left, and the div in question. thats all thats in the header div. Should I give the header div a specific height? Would that help?

Comment: @RoddeyPhipps, please fix your question to include the relevant HTML.  Editing your HTML has already changed the original content once.

Comment: @RoddeyPhipps, see the edits on my answer... they solved your issue with Chrome.  And I meant, use the "edit" link to fix your original posting to include the relevant HTML.  Never mind, I did it for you.

Comment: fixed... thank you SO MUCH. I had forgotten about that overflow thing.

Comment: how do I vote? I'm looking around for a button or something but dont see anything